# Email Sent Via Send Grid is not Displaying styling of HTML for Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, sendgrid, sendmail

I am sending HTML to my back-end and back-end is using Send-Grid to send that HTML to provided email address in body of Email.

**C# Code**

```
public async Task SendEmail(string toAddress, string html)
        {

            var email = new SendGridMessage
            {
                From = new EmailAddress(FromEmailAddress, FromDisplayName),
                HtmlContent = html,
                Personalizations = new List<Personalization>()
                {
                    new Personalization()
                    {
                        Tos = new List<EmailAddress>(){new EmailAddress(toAddress)}
                    }
                },
                PlainTextContent = string.Empty,
                Subject = Subject,
                MailSettings= new MailSettings()

            };
            email.SetClickTracking(false, false);

            await _sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(email);
        }
```

HTML Looks fine when I look it in back-end while debugging.

[image]

But when I check this email within outlook Email within Chrome and Edge browser it looks like this.
[image]
It should look like this actually , it working fine even for external outlook app. Problem is with Chrome and Edge
[image]

I have tried inclining the css in html as well using using Premail Package of .NET

I have tried few things
Before sending email I have tried to replace anchor tags with buttons like `<button> ... </button>`it resolved styling issue in browser but with that button is no more clickable , in other words href is no more working. So in next go I replaced anchor tag with `<a type='button'>..</a>`. Now styling working fine in outlook app but not in browsers and link is no more working in browser

This is the HTML I am recieving at the back-end.

```html
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\">\n<head>\n<!--[if gte mso 9]>\n<xml>\n  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\n    <o:AllowPNG/>\n    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>\n  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\n</xml>\n<![endif]-->\n  <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n  <meta name=\"x-apple-disable-message-reformatting\">\n  <!--[if !mso]><!--><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\"><!--<![endif]-->\n  <title></title>\n  \n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n      @media only screen and (min-width: 520px) {\n  .u-row {\n    width: 500px !important;\n  }\n  .u-row .u-col {\n    vertical-align: top;\n  }\n\n  .u-row .u-col-100 {\n    width: 500px !important;\n  }\n\n}\n\n@media (max-width: 520px) {\n  .u-row-container {\n    max-width: 100% !important;\n    padding-left: 0px !important;\n    padding-right: 0px !important;\n  }\n  .u-row .u-col {\n    min-width: 320px !important;\n    max-width: 100% !important;\n    display: block !important;\n  }\n  .u-row {\n    width: calc(100% - 40px) !important;\n  }\n  .u-col {\n    width: 100% !important;\n  }\n  .u-col > div {\n    margin: 0 auto;\n  }\n}\nbody {\n  margin: 0;\n  padding: 0;\n}\n\ntable,\ntr,\ntd {\n  vertical-align: top;\n  border-collapse: collapse;\n}\n\np {\n  margin: 0;\n}\n\n.ie-container table,\n.mso-container table {\n  table-layout: fixed;\n}\n\n* {\n  line-height: inherit;\n}\n\na[x-apple-data-detectors='true'] {\n  color: inherit !important;\n  text-decoration: none !important;\n}\n\ntable, td { color: #000000; } #u_body a { color: #0000ee; text-decoration: underline; }\n    </style>\n  \n  \n\n</head>\n\n<body class=\"clean-body u_body\" style=\"margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;background-color: #e7e7e7;color: #000000\">\n  <!--[if IE]><div class=\"ie-container\"><![endif]-->\n  <!--[if mso]><div class=\"mso-container\"><![endif]-->\n  <table id=\"u_body\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;table-layout: fixed;border-spacing: 0;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;vertical-align: top;min-width: 320px;Margin: 0 auto;background-color: #e7e7e7;width:100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n  <tbody>\n  <tr style=\"vertical-align: top\">\n    <td style=\"word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top\">\n    <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\"><tr><td align=\"center\" style=\"background-color: #e7e7e7;\"><![endif]-->\n    \n\n<div class=\"u-row-container\" style=\"padding: 0px;background-color: transparent\">\n  <div class=\"u-row\" style=\"Margin: 0 auto;min-width: 320px;max-width: 500px;overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-word;background-color: transparent;\">\n    <div style=\"border-collapse: collapse;display: table;width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color: transparent;\">\n      <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\"><tr><td style=\"padding: 0px;background-color: transparent;\" align=\"center\"><table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"width:500px;\"><tr style=\"background-color: transparent;\"><![endif]-->\n      \n<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align=\"center\" width=\"500\" style=\"width: 500px;padding: 0px;border-top: 0px solid transparent;border-left: 0px solid transparent;border-right: 0px solid transparent;border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;\" valign=\"top\"><![endif]-->\n<div class=\"u-col u-col-100\" style=\"max-width: 320px;min-width: 500px;display: table-cell;vertical-align: top;\">\n  <div style=\"height: 100%;width: 100% !important;\">\n  <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--><div style=\"height: 100%; padding: 0px;border-top: 0px solid transparent;border-left: 0px solid transparent;border-right: 0px solid transparent;border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;\"><!--<![endif]-->\n  \n<table style=\"font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\" role=\"presentation\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\">\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <td style=\"overflow-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-word;padding:10px;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\" align=\"left\">\n        \n  <!--[if mso]><style>.v-button {background: transparent !important;}</style><![endif]-->\n<div align=\"center\">\n  <!--[if mso]><v:roundrect xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" href=\"\" style=\"height:37px; v-text-anchor:middle; width:139px;\" arcsize=\"11%\"  stroke=\"f\" fillcolor=\"#3AAEE0\"><w:anchorlock/><center style=\"color:#FFFFFF;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\"><![endif]-->  \n    <a href=\"\" target=\"_blank\" class=\"v-button\" style=\"box-sizing: border-box;display: inline-block;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;text-align: center;color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #3AAEE0; border-radius: 4px;-webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; width:auto; max-width:100%; overflow-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; word-wrap:break-word; mso-border-alt: none;\">\n      <span style=\"display:block;padding:10px 20px;line-height:120%;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px; line-height: 16.8px;\">Button Bug Text</span></span>\n    </a>\n  <!--[if mso]></center></v:roundrect><![endif]-->\n</div>\n\n      </td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>\n\n<table style=\"font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\" role=\"presentation\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\" border=\"0\">\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <td style=\"overflow-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-word;padding:10px;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;\" align=\"left\">\n        \n  <div style=\"line-height: 140%; text-align: left; word-wrap: break-word;\">\n    <p style=\"font-size: 14px; line-height: 140%;\">This is a new Text block. Change the text.</p>\n  </div>\n\n      </td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>\n\n  <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--></div><!--<![endif]-->\n  </div>\n</div>\n<!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td><![endif]-->\n      <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</div>\n\n\n    <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->\n    </td>\n  </tr>\n  </tbody>\n  </table>\n  <!--[if mso]></div><![endif]-->\n  <!--[if IE]></div><![endif]-->\n</body>\n\n</html>\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML is a language that is not read the same by each technology. Each email client can interpret the HTML format based on its own rules. Edge, Chrome, and Outlook do not share the same interpreter. Outlook uses the MS word processor to interpret HTML. Outlook could be stripping the button from the HTML. Outlook styles could also be ignoring styling. Try something like this: (it should look the same across all email clients)

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width: auto;">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; background-color: #3498db; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center;" valign="top" bgcolor="#3498db" align="center"> <a href="#URL" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; color: #ffffff; background-color: #3498db; border: solid 1px #3498db; border-radius: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0; padding: 12px 25px; text-transform: capitalize; border-color: #3498db;" title="Your buttons title">Button</a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also check out: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ for future projects as it can help with css

Answer (score 1):

It looks different because your html contains [Outlook conditional CSS](https://stackoverflow.design/email/base/mso/).

You can see the html contains the tag `<! [if mso]>`

Meaning, when it detects that it's outlook it takes the html from the tag.
Try removing all the tags manually and then see if it helps.

Comment: I have tried by removing all ```mso``` tags it is still the same

Comment: Make sure you remove all the mso tags. And it's better if you change the settings in the tool that you used to create the html in to not include these tags in the first place.

Comment: I already removed all ```mso``` tags. Still it is not displaying the styling. I don't understand one thing according to the document you shared in your answer mso tags are meant to add styling in html but why aren't the being appended!